# Jupyter notebook clear widget state

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, pre-commit-hook

I use widgets in a Jupyter notebook and save their state (e.g. the "Settings -> Save Widget state automatically" is checked) to the notebook file.
For the sake of git versioning this notebook, I want to clear the widget state again.

I tried:

1. Uncheck the setting in the Jupyter lab frontend, restart the kernel, save again.
2. Uncheck the setting, restart kernel, save, then (horrible) delete the "widgets" field from the json file.

The first approach just saves the state again.
For the second non-usable approach the field "widgets" just gets restored every time I save the notebook.

A preferred solution would be to disable the state saving from within Jupyter lab.

Used versions:

- Jupyterlab 3.4.2
- Jupyterlab_widgets 1.1.0
- IPyWidgets 7.7.0
- Python 3.10

PS: I ended up in using a pre-commit hook, which I patched to remove also the state [pre-commit-jupyter](https://github.com/roy-ht/pre-commit-jupyter/pulls/8)